# How to custom VaR at 5% and max return in Portfolio Analytics

Tags: performanceanalytics, r-portfolioanalytics

For Asset Allocation in R using Portfolio Analytics, is there a way to set risk as constant number, then optimize portfolio returns? For example, to maintain VaR always at 5% (conservative), how do weights of 8 assets change in portfolio to max return? In contrast, how do the weights change compared to a risky (VaR =20%) portfolio? In the Portfolio Analytics package, we can only set min risk as objective, but not set risk as a constant number. (Different from Equal Risk Contribution)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
add.objective(portfolio = base_pf, type = 'VaR', name = 'var', target=0.05)
```

or

```
add.objective(portfolio = base_pf, type = 'VaR', name = 'var', target=0.2)
```

Comment: Ohh I saw too late that this is an old post. Have you figured this one out?